# Is it possible to build SQL where clause from C# function predicate?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, dapper

I am trying to build sql where clause from a function predicate. What I am trying to achieve looks like following:

```
public IEnumerable<TDbEntity> Query(Func<TDbEntity, bool> predicate)
{
 // TODO: to build whereCondText from predicate
 var whereCondText = "";
 var sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE " + whereCondText;
 return DB.Connection.Query<TDbEntity>(sql);
}
```

Comment: I am using dapper.

Comment: Does https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions / https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/wiki/Predicates help?

Comment: The thing you want to do is exactly what ORMs do but instead of delegates, they do it from `Expression`. So to answer your question: yes you can do this with `Expression` but it is not easy. A better question is why you want to do this if ORMs can do this already?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so, but the predicate would have to be in the form of `Expression<Func<TDbEntity, bool>>`. This tells the compiler to build an AST representation of your code instead of emitting the IL for the code. You can then use `ExpressionVisitor` to walk the tree and create the predicate.

This is not a trivial task. You are probably better off using Entity Framework or Draper or nHibernate. For simple expression you might be able to do a decent job.

Comment: Not really, I have used `ExpressionVisitor` but it is not a trivial task to accomplish a Expression tree to SQL transformation, it depends on how you map your class to the SQL tables and columns .. again an ORM is probably better for you

Comment: This would be the standard doc for this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882521(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: But, as a personal opinion , this is going to be a black hole of bugs, and you will have to deal with the because nobody on your team will want to touch the code. Use and ORM, save yourself the trouble. Unless you are creating a library for use in more projects and you have very specific need this is not worth it.